# Repeat DoubleAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want to apply the following animation to my Window:

```
var ani = new DoubleAnimation(610, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.7));
BeginAnimation(Window.WidthProperty, ani);
```

The problem is that this animation works only the first time, the other times it has no effect.
Why? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the fromValue when you create the `DoubleAnimation` (as first argument).

```
var ani = new DoubleAnimation(ActualWidth, 610, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.7));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code:

```
ani.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
```

The animation will repeat itself once it is finished with `RepeatBehavior` set to Forever

Comment: I don't want to repeat my animation forever.... Only when I call the BeginAnimation method.

Comment: When exactly do you need to begin your animation? At random times? It may be more suited to use a XAML `Trigger` for this matter

Comment: For example when I click a button.

Comment: Can you add the XAML code of your button? Adding a trigger to the button.Click event will trigger the animation every time you click on it

Comment: There isn't a button, it is just an example, I have a List view and when I select an Item I want to start my animation. I need to know why it works only the first time.